# How to access dynamic column in pyspark dataframe

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to pyspark. I have list of columns in an array like below.

```
input_vars = [
'column1',
'column2',    
'column3',
'column4'
]
```

Now I want to do something like below using dataframe.

```
for var in input_vars:
    print(df.var.isNotNull())
```

But I'm getting below error when I try to execute above code

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'var'
```

### **EDIT**

I have tried df[var].isNotNull() as per the suggestion given by 'ernest_k' and the above error got resolved. Now my actual requirement is to rewrite below pandas dataframe code into pyspark dataframe.

```
for var in input_vars:
    bindt = df2[df2[var].notnull()][var].quantile([0,.1,.2,.3,.4,.5,.6,.7,.8,.9,1]).unique()

    q0 = df2[df2[var].notnull()][var].quantile(0)
    q1 = df2[df2[var].notnull()][var].quantile(0.25)
    q2 = df2[df2[var].notnull()][var].quantile(0.5)
    q3 = df2[df2[var].notnull()][var].quantile(0.75)
    q4 = df2[df2[var].notnull()][var].quantile(1)
```

Can anyone please help me how to achieve above requirement. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `df[var]`

Comment: @ernest_k - Thanks for your reply. When I tried df[var].isNotNull() I'm getting like Column<isnotnull(column1) instead of boolean value.

Comment: Moreover, `print(df.var.isNotNull())` doesn't work, what is your requirement here?

Comment: @Valli69 Those give you a column object, I suppose. You probably want to try `df.filter(df[var].isNotNull()).show()` to see the filtered data frame (but doing that in a loop over all columns can be dangerous, unless you're just testing, on a small dataset).

Comment: @DuyNguyenHoang Actually my requirement is I want to calculate quantile of a not null column. In pandas I have calculated like df[df[var].notnull()][var].quantile(0.25) but not sure how to do in pyspark dataframe

Comment: Updated answer, check it please

Answer (score 1):

To get the list of columns from DataFrame, use `df.columns` and from there, you can process next step.

In Spark 2.0+, you can use (I am not 100% guarantee that `approxQuantile(var, [0.5], 0.25)` meet your requirement, please change it)

```
columns = df.columns

for var in input_vars:
    if var in columns:
        print(df.filter('{} is not null'.format(var)).approxQuantile(var, [0.5], 0.25))
    else:
        print('Column {} not found'.format(var))
```

More detail, please prefer to [approxQuantile](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.approxQuantile)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I need it in spark 1.6. Can you please suggest in spark 1.6

Comment: I am going to check it tomorrow, and tell you later. Honestly, I have never done it before